# Saved Sqlite Image Appears Totally Black On Uploaded Server Database

Tags: delphi, sqlite, firemonkey

I have an interesting problem.  I have to take a signature image that is saved in Sqlite3 database.

When you view the saved signature on the Sqlite3 database it is a signature.  The database is uploaded to a server that has MSSQL Server which then reads the signature image.  Unfortunately this image appears totally black on the server and it comes back the same.  The db administrator says that the data appears to be garbage (includes unicode characters).

```
Example of the image data is:
Sent Data:  Tried to include but unfortunately it will not show unicode.  It is thousands of bytes long.
Returned Data:  *System.Byte[]*   <<and that is it - 26 bytes long.
```

My guess is that the unicode is responsible.  Not sure how to resolve this issue.

The data connection component is TSQLConnection.  The query component is TSQLQuery.  I am using XE5 building a Firemonkey iOS mobile application.

Here is my code.  Appreciate any help.

```
function SaveSig: boolean;
var
  fStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  fStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    try
      fStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      fStream.Position := 0;
      if Assigned(imgSig) then
      begin
        imgSig.Bitmap.SaveToStream(fStream);
        Result := SqlInsertSig(fStream);
      end;
    except
      on e: Exception do
        ShowMessage(ERROR_BITMAP + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(fStream) then
      FreeAndNil(fStream);
  end;
end;

function SqlInsertSig(const ms: TMemoryStream): boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    try
      sq.Active := False;
      sq.CommandText := 'Insert Into Signatures (Id, Sig) Values (' +
        QuotedStr(IntToStr(Id)) + ', :sig)';
      sq.Params.ParamByName('sig').LoadFromStream(ms, ftBlob);
      Result := (sq.ExecSQL > 0);
    except
      on e: Exception do
        MessageDlg(e.Message, TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
    end;
  finally
    sq.Active := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column in which you are trying to save the image on the MS Sql Server?  Please add that to your q.  I am asking because it seems strange that the DBA can see it.

Comment: MSQSQL it is saved as "IMAGE".  SQLITE it is "BLOB".  Also I found that when trying to send it to Crystal Reports it is a black image.

Comment: (My earlier comment querying your dataset type was based on the fact that TSqlQery didn't used to have a CommandText property, and I'd overlooked that fact that it has since been added, sorry). If you haven't already, I suggest you temporarily add a DBGrid, DBNavigator and TDBImage component to your form (I'd use a VCL form for this)and check that you can successfully load, say, a Bmp file into the Sig column of your Sql Server table, and save it to disk, then have a look at whether Explorer displays it correctly.

Comment: The problem is that Sqlite saves the image as a unicode png.

Comment: So,the image isn't being saved into the Sqlite database by your code, correct?  If so, I can't immediately see how we could help, unless you could make a sample db - with just one or two rows in it - available somehow e.g. via pastebin.  Any chance of that?